# Formula that calculates the distance between origin$\to$destination#1$\to$destination#2 and so on.

Tags: linear-algebra, measure-theory

I wonder if anybody knows a formula that will calculate the distance between origin and multiple destinations. For example:

Origin: $A$ //is only one origin.

Destinations: $B, C, D, E$. /I have got 20 destinations.

$A\to B, A\to C, A\to E$. //that's the distance between origin and each destination. I have it in $m/km$.

What I want to do is next:

$A\to B, B\to C, C\to D, D\to E$. //Basically calculate the distance between one place and another.

Also, how would I represent that in a graph?

Comment: It's not possible...

Comment: How then should I do? Or what should I add to make it possible?

Comment: It's just not a possible problem, it's not enough information (by a long shot). You might want to consider polar coordinates, but that won't change the dearth of information;

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = p_0$ be the origin and $p_1, \cdots, p_n \in \mathbb R^2$ the $n$ destinations of distance $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ to $A$. (These play the role of your $B, C, D, E, \cdots$.) By the triangle inequality, the distance between $p_i$ and $p_{i+1}$ is at most $x_i + x_{i+1}$, so an upper bound on the length of your path is $$x_1 + (x_1 + x_2) + (x_2 + x_3) + \cdots + (x_{n-1} + x_n) = x_n + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i.$$ 
There is also a lower bound of $x_1$, since the length of the path is at least the length of the leg from $A$ to $p_1$.

If the points $p_1, \cdots, p_n$ are allowed to coincide, i.e. $p_i = p_j$, then this upper bound is attained if $p_i = (1, 0)$ if $i$ is odd and $p_i = (-1, 0)$ if $i$ is even. On the other hand, the lower bound is attained if $p_i \equiv p_1 = (1, 0)$, i.e. all the points are the same. Even if the points are not permitted to be the same the conclusion is unchanged; by continuity we perturb the points to yield $p_i \neq p_j$.

In other words, without (significantly) more control over the points you can make the length of your path as close as desired to the lower and upper bounds. In particular even in the case where the points lie on the unit circle, i.e. the distances are all one, $x_i \equiv 1$, depending on the points the length of the path can be made arbitrarily close to $2n+1$ or $1$.